# Is there a way to use the fuzzywuzzy python package to exactly match one part of a string and partially match the other?

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

I'm trying to determine if one specific business exists in two different datasets. There are a few things that are making this more complicated than simply doing a join in SQL to only return identical rows in the two datasets:

1. There is no shared ID
2. The names of the same business are often formatted slightly differently in the two datasets (example: ds1 says JT's Kitchen and ds2 says J.T.'s Kitchen)
3. There could be two different businesses with identical names

First stack overflow post, so forgive me if I miss on some etiquette.

I'm attempting to use fuzzywuzzy to return a score on how similar the two business names are. However, i was thinking that to get a more accurate score, I could create a string by concatenating the business nam and zip code, then trying to get an exact match on the zip code part and a fuzzy match on the rest - I am just not sure how to separate what types of match i am looking for on which parts. Alternatively could separate zip code and business name into two separate columns. Here is a version of what i have so far, where ds1.ds1_id is the name+zip from one database and ds2.ds2_id is the name+zip from the second database.

I did want to take a look at all the scores to decide which one i ultimately want to use.

Is there a way to make this exact match on the last 5 digits of strings ds1_id and ds2_id and then fuzzy match on the rest, or am i wasting my time?

````
accountid = []
ds1_id = []
actual_name = []
similarity = []
similarity_partial = []
similarity_set = []
similarity_sort = []

for i in ds1.biz_ID:
        ratio = process.extract(i, ds2.ds2_ID, limit=1)
        partial_ratio = process.extract(i, ds2.ds2_ID, limit=1,scorer=fuzz.partial_ratio)
        token_set_ratio = process.extract(i, ds2.ds2_ID, limit=1,scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio)
        token_sort_ratio = process.extract(i, ds2.ds2_ID, limit=1,scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
        actual_name.append(ratio[0][0])
        similarity.append(ratio[0][1])
        similarity_partial.append(partial_ratio[0][1])
        similarity_set.append(token_set_ratio[0][1])
        similarity_sort.append(token_sort_ratio[0][1])

ds1['actual_name'] = pd.Series(actual_name)
ds1['similarity'] = pd.Series(similarity)
ds1['similarity_partial'] = pd.Series(similarity_partial)
ds1['similarity_set'] = pd.Series(similarity_set)
ds1['similarity_sort'] = pd.Series(similarity_sort)```
````

Comment: I would suggest doing a match on the zip codes first to limit the set of businesses to compare, and then do a fuzzy match of the names on the remaining dataset, unless you have reason to believe there could be cases where the zip code could be incorrect but close to the correct value in one of the data sets.